# Storing a timestamp variable in a FOR command to do stuff with

Tags: batch-file

Why can't I store this?

```
FOR %%a IN ("some_file_path") DO (
    SET FileDateTime=%%~ta
    echo !FileDateTime!
)
```

Output is ~ta

This doesn't work either.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%a IN ("some_file_path") DO (
    SET FileDateTime=!!~ta
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such code works

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
FOR %%a IN ("some_file_path") DO (
    ECHO %%a
    SET FileDateTime=%%~ta
    ECHO !FileDateTime!
)
```

Comment: why do you use `enabledelayedexpansion` ? This maybe goes wrong.

Comment: Two reasons: 1) this is the way to get value returned in the for operator scope. 2) original answer uses it in code samples so I guess author understand that will go. Another solution with call from foxidrive has another limitations

Answer (score 1):

These should work too:

A:

```
FOR %%a IN ("some_file_path") DO (
    SET FileDateTime=%%~ta
    call echo %%FileDateTime%%
)
```

B:

```
FOR %%a IN ("some_file_path") DO (
    SET FileDateTime=%%~ta
)
    echo %FileDateTime%
```